# Why is Mercurial ignoring the repo path I give it in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, mercurial

I'm trying to write a Powershell script to do some things with the output I get from a Mercurial log command. Here's what I've got so far:

```
param([string] $Path, [string] $From, [string] $To)
$file_list = hg log -R ${Path} -r ${From}:${To} --style fileList
$file_list
```

When I run this .ps1 script from a prompt (current working directory is my desktop), I get the following error:

```
hg.exe : abort: :tip not under root
```

I added quotes around the command so I can see exactly what's getting run like this:

```
param([string] $Path, [string] $From, [string] $To)
$file_list = "hg log -R ${Path} -r ${From}:${To} --style fileList"
$file_list
```

When I call it like this:

```
.\MyScript.ps1 -Path .\Projects\MyProject -From 80 -To tip
```

The output is exactly what I wanted:

```
hg log -R .\Projects\MyProject -r 80:tip --style fileList
```

If I copy and paste that output directly into my command line, the log command works correctly.

I can't find any good documentation on this error message.  I know this directory is a repo.  Is it not actually using the directory I specified for the repo root?  Is Powershell doing something to the path I'm passing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was the colon between ${From} and ${To}. I fixed it by escaping the colon with a backtick (`). Changing the script to:

```
param([string] $Path, [string] $From, [string] $To)
$file_list = hg log -R ${Path} -r ${From}`:${To} --style fileList
$file_list
```

runs the log command as expected.

In short, **beware of colons in Powershell**!

Answer (score 2):

Powershell has problems around passing arguments to exe.

Just assigning the command line to a string and seeing the contents of that string will not help you here.

There is a util called `echoargs.exe`, which comes as part of the [Powershell Community Extensions.](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)

Get that and pass the arguments that you are passing to `hg` to it, it will echo back the actual arguments that were supplied from Powershell.

Comment: Looks like the first argument is being displayed by echoargs as "<.\Projects\Myproject>. Where are those angle brackets coming from?  Putting quotes around the path as I pass it in doesn't seem to get rid of them.  Doing a GetType() on $Path just shows it as a String. Help?

Comment: If it says `Arg 0 is <log>`, log is the arg. Don't include the `<>`

Comment: Then the path is exactly what it's supposed to be. What gives? The command works perfectly when I type it on the command line directly.

Comment: @BrianSullivan - Commandline as in cmd? And is the error the same?

Comment: I was actually using the PowerShell console, but I verified that it works via cmd as well.

Comment: @BrianSullivan - Are you saying that it works from console, but not when you run it as a script?

Comment: Correct. I can run 'hg log -R .\Projects\MyProject' -r 80 tip --style fileList' just fine at either cmd or PS prompt. When I run the script I get the error I listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pass the repository as the first argument; it needs to be passed to the `-R` parameter.  This version of your PowerShell would work:

```
param([string] $Path, [string] $From, [string] $To)
$file_list  = hg log -R ${Path} -r ${From}:${To} --style fileList
$file_list
```

Comment: We actually try to infer the `-R` flag from the command line arguments. So if you're outside a repository, then you can do `hg log my-repo/foo`. If you're already inside another repo, then you're told `abort: my-repo/foo not under root`. So I'm not sure that is the problem here.

Comment: I'd actually tried that as well, and got an error message.  See amended question.  Not to be argumentative, but I ran that command without the -R and it worked fine.  Are you sure it's not a positional parameter? Edit: Looks like Martin confirmed that. Glad I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 0):

For calling `exe`s with arguments in Powershell, I use `&`.

What has always worked for me is putting the `exe` path in a variable, and then each of my args in other variables to keep things tidy (just something like `$arg=-d myArg`) and then invoking the following:

`& "$path" "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3"` and so on.